# Printer found but won't print

Tags: networking, printer

I have a network printer, model is Canon MF4890. I have downloaded correct drivers, opened all ports between the printer and the rest of the LAN on the firewall, and can find the printer through CUPS or by using the printer's web interface. When I try to print, CUPS says processing, but nothing prints. Sometimes the printer comes out of sleep mode as if it is being talked to.

/var/log/cups/error_log shows:

```
W [05/Jun/2019:18:17:22 -0600] CreateProfile failed: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:profile id \'Canon-MF4800-Gray..\' already exists
```

Why is my printer found but not printing?